Survival probability Amoeba population
I have a question regarding the already covered Amoeba problem. Here is the set up: Every minute, an amoeba may die, stay the same, split into two or split into three with equal probability. All its offspring, will behave the same.
In my first attempt to solve this problem, I used the law of total probability to derive a recursion formula for the event that the amoeba population will die out. This led me to following formula $p = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}p + \frac{1}{4}p^2 + \frac{1}{4}p^3$, where $p = P[\text{pop. dies}] = P[\text{pop. dies}|\text{stays the same}]P[\text{stays the same}] + P[\text{pop. dies}|\text{population doubles}]P[\text{population doubles}] + P[\text{pop. dies}|\text{population triples}]P[\text{population triples}] + P[\text{pop. dies}|\text{population dies}]P[\text{population dies}] = \frac{1}{4}P[\text{pop. dies}] + \frac{1}{4}P[\text{pop. dies}]^2 + \frac{1}{4}P[\text{pop. dies}]^3 + \frac{1}{4}*1 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}p + \frac{1}{4}p^2 + \frac{1}{4}p^3$.
Solving this formula, I get $p=1, p=-1+-\sqrt{2}$, since $p=1$ can't hold (positive expected value of amoeba pop.) and probabilities must be positive, I concluded $p=\sqrt{2} - 1$.
After solving this, I tried to derive a recursion formula for the survival probability. This led me to the recursion:
$q = P[\text{pop. survives}] = P[\text{pop. survives}|\text{stays the same}]P[\text{stays the same}] + P[\text{pop. survives}|\text{population doubles}]P[\text{population doubles}] + P[\text{pop. survives}|\text{population triples}]P[\text{population triples}] + P[\text{pop. survives}|\text{population dies}]P[\text{population dies}] = \frac{1}{4}P[\text{pop. survives}] + \frac{1}{4}P[\text{pop. survives}]^2 + \frac{1}{4}P[\text{pop. survives}]^3 + \frac{1}{4}*0 = \frac{1}{4}q + \frac{1}{4}q^2 + \frac{1}{4}q^3$
This approach is wrong since it leads to probabilities larger than 1.
I am not able to find my mistake and appreciate any help finding my misconception.
Follow-up question: Is there a way to solve and transform this problem using a transition graph and calculating absorption probabilities?
Thanks!

For  what is p=.. the correct  formula? This formula gives only a negativ value of p?

I edited my question. Is it clear now?

Suppose the amoeba first divides in two. This creates two "subpopulations". Think about the following. (a) How many subpopulations have to die for the overall poupulatiob to die? (b) How many subpopulations have to survive for the overall population to survive? You treat these questions as if they have the same answer, but they don't. Finding the difference will show you what's wrong with your survival probability computation.

Ahh I see. In a) both subpopulations have to die and in b) only one of the subpopulation must survive. Therefore, in a) we can reduce our assumption that the population dies only because the events are somewhat "equivalent", that is the entire population dies iff every member of the population dies. Thank you @Ziv!

I just realized that a) is a logical AND and b) is a logical OR, aka. inclusion exclusion principle should yield the solution in b)

And rewriting the recursion for q using the inclusion-exclusion principle yields to a very ugly equation. Thank you! Now I understand why we favor logical AND over logical OR in this case / to derive recursion formulas.

Yep, and vs. or is exactly the key distinction!
